# Проверка условия выхода из цикла

Tags: c++, оптимизация

Будет ли выигрыш в скорости работы цикла при таких изменениях?

```
bool flag = true; // флаг выхода из цикла
int count = 10000000; // максимальное кол-во итераций

while (count && flag)
{
   int a, b;
   // вычисляем a и b, делаем --count;
   // ... 

// исходный вариант
   if (a != b) 
     flag = false;
// "улучшение" 1 
   if (flag && a != b)
     flag = false;
// "улучшение" 2
   if (a != b && flag = false) ;

   // ...
}
```

Comment: А если просто `if (a != b) break;`

Comment: @VladimirGamalian после условий может ещё идти код, сейчас исправлю

Comment: а в чём смысл улучшения, если мы выставили `flag = false`, то мы выйдем из цикла на след итерации и всё. Мне исходный вариант кажется не медленнее остальных.

Comment: Ещё напишите в чем именно улучшение у вариантов "улучшение 1" и "улучшение 2"

Comment: Ну вот напишут Вам, к примеру, «будет» или «не будет», что дальше?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Медленным звеном в данном алгоритме, что вполне очевидно, является вычисление `a` и `b` на каждой итерации цикла. Чтобы не вычислять `a` и `b` по 100000 раз, следует применить алгоритм последовательного приближения `a` к `b`. Ведь по сути данный алгоритм перебирает разные варианты с той единственной целью, когда `a == b`.

Таким образом, его следует аналитически разложить на две функции:

- `f(count) = a(count)`
- `g(count) = b(count)`

Затем найти корни уравнения `f(count) = g(count)`. И вычислять корень уравнения всего 1 раз вместо 100000 циклов.

Comment: не факт что это возможно, функции могут зависеть от различные глобальных состояний и аналитически выразить зависимость не тривиально.

Comment: Не зря же я упомянул метод последовательного приближения https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8